# Hide a button outside of function

Tags: swift

Using Swift 5.5 and have a UIButton that gets created in

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error)
```

I have a custom error page that shows on that page and as part of it I show a button to refresh the page

```
buttonReload.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .touchUpInside) 
mWebKit.addSubview(buttonReload)
```

For various reasons in my organization, the first time this app loads when installed, it may pull up this error page.  However I also have a welcome screen and when it finishes I reload the WKWebview in

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
```

So that happens automatically and the error page that is in the `WKWebView` goes away but the button on that page never goes away because no one clicked it in this case.

When `viewWillAppear` reloads the content, is there a way to pass a

```
buttonReload.isHidden = true
```

when viewWillAppear doesn't have access to it?

Guess the easy way to ask this is if a button is created in func webView... how do I access it in func viewWillAppear to hide it?  Or maybe get rid of the subView?

Comment: Store a reference to the button as a property on your view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jnpdx mentioned, after you create the button at the class level.

```
private weak var button: UIButton?
```

Then in your didFailProvisionalNavigation you assign your created button to the class level one:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    self.button = buttonReload
}
```

After you had done that you can call it from where ever you like:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let button = self.button {
        button.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm going to give this a try.  One question, in viewWillAppear, if for some reason the button is already hidden, will setting it to true cause any issues?  Do I need to check the current status before hiding the button?  Whenever viewWillAppear triggers should always be visible but never know so  curious.

Comment: It shouldn’t cause any issues